# How to run Fisher's Exact test (in R) with multiple levels?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, fishers-exact-test

I have a data set that is separated by Stimulus Type, Sex, and Observed/Expected. I have many stimulus types (more than 100), and want to run a Fisher's Exact test on EACH to see if there is a difference in observed vs expected ratios between the sexes. In other words, do males respond more often to a given stimulus than females (more often than is expected)?

Example:

[image]

Is it possible to run a Fisher's test with this structure? Or should I look for a different test? I have seen lots of guidelines for running Fisher's in R, but not with multiple levels. Just looking for advice if there is a way to do this or not!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Dave2e apologies for not being more clear! I was just looking for guidance if this was even possible in R or if we should look into a different kind of test. I hadn't seen fisher's run this way before. I've edited the question, hopefully that's more useful now

Comment: It is possible to do Fisher's exact test for contigency tables larger than 2x2, but for 100 levels it is unlikely that your computer (or anyone's...) will be able to do the calculations. If you mean doing 100 independent Fisher's tests, that is also possible in R but will have hugely inflated FDR/FWER.